# my program wont work properly and my function keeps throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault

so I have this code that with a function is supposed to take all the numbers in a 2D array and print them to the second power but my code keeps throwing segmentation fault and i don't know why

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void er(int arr[][100000000], int, int);

int main()
{

    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int arr[n][100000000];

    er(arr, n, m);

    return 0;
}

void er(int arr[][100000000], int n, int m)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] *= arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<m;i++)` should be `for(int j=0;j<m;j++)`

Comment: i already fixed that and it keeps on throwing segmentation fault

Comment: Did you fix both occurrences? Also `int arr[n][100000000];` is not standard C++, you should be using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead

Comment: `int arr[n][100000000]` is not valid C++, since `n` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>   
using namespace std;` <-- stop doing that, *now*.

Comment: `int arr[n][100000000]` even if this was valid c++ code this is way too big for the stack.

Answer (score 8):

Using

```
int arr[n][100000000];
```

is problematic on two accounts.

1. VLAs are not standard C++. It is supported by some compilers as an extension.
2. The size `100000000` is too large for a variable on the stack. Changing that to `100` and making sure that `m` is less than or equal to `100` will most likely work as long as your compiler supports VLAs.

A better alternative would be to use `std::vector`.

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n, std::vector<int>(m));
```

Of course, that will require you to change the function `er` accordingly.

In addition, please don't use

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for further details.